# read value from CGI response, using javascript, HTML

Tags: javascript, html, cgi

I'm building a page to execute simple cgi commands sent to an ip camera, this way the user can enable or disable the motion detection configuration from the page clicking a button instead of login to the camera's webgui.
I have figure out how to send the cgi commands and in response the camera response with a new window where the only content is:

```
<CGI_Result>
    <result>0</result>
</CGI_Result>
```

0 = the command was received and executed.

Is there a way that I can read this and show an alert() to the user being more explicit (saying that the command went ok), all this using html+javascript?

also, is there a wway a I can determine and show a message to the user when the cgi dont response? if this is the case the new browser window will open but will show a message "the connection has time out" (this in forefox)

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0):

In general, you would use [XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest) for this sort of thing, but (given the assumption that you aren't hosting the HTML document on the camera itself and can't [configure CORS on the camera](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS)) you will bounce off [the same origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy) so — **No**.

This also assumes that by "html+javascript" you are referring to browser-side JavaScript. If you were using differently hosted JavaScript (such as [Node.js](https://nodejs.org/en/)) then you would probably have other options (such as [the http module](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_get_options_callback)).